# apache2 refuses to load self built php 5.2.8 module

Tags: php, apache

I need to downport something to php 5 and tried to build php 5.2.8 and replace the normal php7.0 by it.
However, when I start apache2 I get the following error message:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 147 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf: 
    Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: 
    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: 
    undefined symbol: php_ini_scanned_path`
```

When I look at the exported symbols, php_ini_scanned_path doesn't look ok:

```
root@host:~/Downloads/php-5.2.8# readelf -s libs/libphp5.so | grep php_ini
    76: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_ini_scanned_path
    86: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_ini_scanned_files
   182: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_ini_opened_path
   250: 0000000000214cf8     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 apache2_php_ini_path_over
   293: 000000000000b930    82 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 zif_php_ini_loaded_file
   297: 000000000000b920    12 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 zif_php_ini_scanned_files
   196: 0000000000214cf8     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 apache2_php_ini_path_over
   210: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_ini_scanned_path
   222: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_ini_scanned_files
   336: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_ini_opened_path
   340: 000000000000b930    82 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 zif_php_ini_loaded_file
   365: 000000000000b920    12 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 zif_php_ini_scanned_files
```

I built the module with

```
./configure --with-apxs2 --prefix=/usr/lib/apache2/php
make
```

Can someone help me find the incompatibility that causes this?
OS is kali 2.0.

Comment: Apache `2.what` it matters

Comment: PHP5.2 probably wont talk to Apache 2,3 or 2.4 as the communication between the 2 changed in Apache 2,3. So you may have to also revert Apache to 2.2

Comment: apache 2.4.25. Thanks.